# set MAVEN_HOME in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have this line of code in a project in eclipse & it's giving me error.

```
Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker(); 
invoker.setMavenHome(new File(System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME")));  //giving error
```

So I ran and its giving blank line as output

```
echo $MAVEN_HOME
```

However, I am able to run other maven projects through command prompt and through eclipse.
I have following question..

Q 1. what is the difference between the following two commands

```
whereis maven
maven: /etc/maven /usr/share/maven
```

& when I run

```
whereis mvn
mvn: /usr/bin/mvn /usr/bin/X11/mvn /usr/share/man/man1/mvn.1.gz
```

Q 2. what do I need to put in .bashrc... please tell me exactly...

this is my current content of .bashrc file

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

EDIT

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Just a side note, if you are using maven `2` or above then you have to work with `M2_HOME` instead of `MAVEN_HOME`. Type `mvn --version` to get informations about your installation.

Comment: thanks @A4L I am using 3.0.4

Comment: @anish As I am new to maven, just tell me echo $MAVEN_HOME , giving a blank line is OK ?

Comment: @Bhavisha Which OS you are Using,try setting MAVEN_HOME environment variable,add the following entry MAVEN_HOME=<Maven Install Directory> in your .bashrc file, and then source it source ~/.basrc file, then try echo $MAVEN_HOME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to use in eclipse you can add this in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables.

Just add new variable with name `MAVEN_HOME`.

But for executions you need to set in in Run/Debug configuration - probably that's what you need.

```
whereis maven
```

is about directory, and

```
whereis mvn
```

is about executable file.

For .bashrc:

```
MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven
export MAVEN_HOME
```

Comment: MAVEN_HOME= which path ?
I am using apache maven 3.0.4

Comment: could not get it done... please tell what path should I put ??

Comment: As you wrote in question, the path is /usr/share/maven

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `MAVEN_HOME` in `bashrc` file but set it in the Environment tab of the launcher configuration of Eclipse.

The .bashrc file is for the bash environment

Comment: hey could you please tell me where is that(laucher configuration of Eclipse) ? :)

Comment: Run | Run configurations.. Click on the run configuration you want to change

Answer (score 0):

Basically `invoker.setMavenHome(MAVEN_HOME);` this needs the home directory where you have installed maven. If you need to find where is the home directory of maven. You can you use following approaches as you tried.

```
      whereis maven
```

This will be showing where is the location which maven has been installed into your computer.

```
       maven: /etc/maven /usr/share/maven
```